# Cocos2dx : How to stop CCFollow moving the ParallaxNode and making background black

Tags: c++, windows, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

I am trying to follow my heroSprite using CCFollow, but there are two erratic behaviors that are happening .

I am making the camera follow my sprite as follows :

> startSprite = CCSprite::createWithSpriteFrameName("santa_001.png"); 
>   startSprite->setPosition(ccp (size.width / 5 , size.height / 2 ));
>   this->addChild(startSprite,1);
>   **this->runAction(CCFollow::create(heroSprite, CCRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height * 2)));**

Now, what happens is :

**a) The background Parallax Node consisting of different sprites and moving at different speed are also moving in "upward" direction when the heroSprite jumps upward. I want to keep this sprites at their original position and not move upward with the heroSprite. How do I do that ?**

> voidNode = CCParallaxNodeExtras::node();
>
> voidNode->addChild(pSpriteGrass, 2, ccp(3.0f,0), ccp(0,
>   size.height/10 - 50) );
>   voidNode->addChild(pSpriteGrass02, 3,
>   ccp(3.0f,0), ccp(size.width - 10 , size.height/10 - 50) );
>     voidNode->addChild(pSprite, 1, ccp(1.0f,0), ccp(0, size.height/10 -
>   50) );    voidNode->addChild(pSprite02, 0, ccp(1.0f,0), ccp(size.width -
>   10, size.height/10 - 50) );
>
> voidNode->addChild(pSpriteSky02, 0, ccp(0.6f,0), ccp(0, size.height
>   /2 + 75) );   voidNode->addChild(pSpriteSky, 1, ccp(0.6f,0),
>   ccp(size.width, size.height /2 + 75) );
>
> voidNode->addChild(pSpriteStars, 2, ccp(2.0f,0), ccp(0, size.height -
>   110) );   voidNode->addChild(pSpriteStars02, 3, ccp(2.0f,0),
>   ccp(size.width - 10, size.height - 110) );
>
> voidNode->addChild(pSpriteClouds, 4, ccp(1.2f,0), ccp(0, size.height
>   - 110) );     voidNode->addChild(pSpriteClouds02, 5, ccp(1.2f,0), ccp(size.width - 10, size.height - 110) );
>
> CCActionInterval* go = CCMoveBy::create(25, ccp(-1000,0) );
>       CCSequence* seq = CCSequence::create(go, NULL);
>       voidNode->runAction( (CCRepeatForever::create(seq) ));
>
> ```
> this->addChild( voidNode, 0 );
> ```

**b) When the hero moves upward, the screen which is initialized with white color turns black for sometime when the heroSprite is jumping. When it comes down the screen becomes white again. How do I make the upward portion of the screen white as well ?**

> CC_BREAK_IF(! CCLayerColor::initWithColor( **ccc4(255,255,255,255)** ) );

Any suggestions or pointers would be helpful . Thanks

---

**UPDATE FOR PART B :**

**Through "Smugbit Studios" suggestion, I changed**

> **initWithColor:ccc4(255,255,255,255);**

**to**

> **initWithColor(ccc4(255, 255, 255, 255), size.width, size.height * 2);**

**and it solves my problem . I am still looking to solve answer part a .**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a, set the bounds of the CCFollow to whatever you want the max height to be - in this case, I believe it would just be size.height, so:

```
this->runAction(CCFollow::create(heroSprite, CCRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)));
```

For b, I suspect your main init of "this" is a CCLayer, and not a CCLayerColor. Just change what you are subclassing to CCLayerColor, and change the new init to:

```
initWithColor:ccc4(255,255,255,255)
```

Edit: Correction for answer B - you also need to define the layer size. If not defined, it is set to the screen size, but it would appear you are trying to go beyond the height of the screen. In that case, use:

```
initWithColor(ccc4(255, 255, 255, 255), width, height)
```

Where height is the maximum height you will display - likely (size.height*2).

Comment: For your answer b), changing initWithColor:ccc4(255,255,255,255); to initWithColor(ccc4(255, 255, 255, 255), size.width, size.height * 2); solves my problem ... But I am still stuck at problem a), I don't need to move the background sprites to follow my heroSprite..

Comment: As I mentioned, the CCRectMake portion of CCFollow defines the boundary of the following. Setting it to a lower value will prevent the background from following after the defined height.

Comment: Setting it to size.height or lower, doesn't make the camera follow the sprite :(

Comment: Only if I make it higher does it follow the sprite, but the background sprites move as well

Comment: Ah, you still want the camera to follow, but not the background. To do that, you just need to change the voidNode->addChild() definitions to -1 for the y axis:  for example, ccp(0.6f,-1.0f).

Comment: And keep the boundary to size.height*2. This will have the background appear to move down as the layer moves up.

Comment: :) Thank you very much , for me the ccp(0.6f,+1.0f), +1 for the y axis did the trick.